# filter objects using foreignkeys

Tags: python, django, filter

So I have a form where user can post `Parent` details also form for Kid for a different model.

what i need is to allow users to access list of `Parent` objects by filtering their related objects `Kid`

let's say a filter to list Parents objects that has children named `X` older than `Z` live in `Y` city AND has no children named `X` who is younger than `Z` live in `Y` city .

**models.py** :

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Kid(models.Model):
    cities = (
        ('city1', city1),
        ('city2', city2)
    )
    family = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    city = models.CharField(choices=cities)
```

any idea how to do it or where/what to look for the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Related manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) seems like a feasible option.

> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships
>   in lookups, taking care of the `SQL JOINs` for you automatically, behind
>   the scenes. To span a relationship, just use the field name of related
>   fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get
>   to the field you want.
>
> It works backwards, too. To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model.

```
parents = Parent.objects.filter(kid__name=X,kid__age__gte=Y,kid__city=Z)
```

PS: I have not tested this code. The intention is to give a suggestion on approach.

Edit 1: Addressing the exclude exception as pointed in the comments. [Link to Django documentation. Refer to the note in this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)

Exclude behavior is different than filter. Exclude in related manager doesn't use a combination of conditions instead excludes both eg. `Parent.objects.exclude(kid__name=X,kid__city=Z)` will exclude kids with name `X` and kids from city `Z` instead of kids with name `X` who are from city `Z`

Django suggested approach is:

```
Parent.objects.exclude(kid__in=Kid.objects.filter(name=X,city=Z))
```

Comment: It wouldn't work this easy. Because it will be `kid_set`, not `kid`. This is one to many relation.

Comment: I am sorry @SardorbekImomaliev, I do not follow you. The OP's sample model is exactly the same as the example model in Django documentation. What am I missing?

Comment: Kid has a Parent, but Parent has many Kids. In example Entity has a Blog, but Blog can have many Entities, and relation field on parent will be called `kid_set`

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev this example lead me to think that we can filter parent based on information in kid
`Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon')`

Comment: `This example retrieves all Blog objects which have at least one Entry whose headline contains 'Lennon'.` So it will not solve problem of excluding parents that have only this filter pattern

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev you are right about exclude. Updating the answer to reflect the exclude related information.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in reversed logic. Firstly you need to change `age` to `IntegerField` otherwise you wouldn't be able to compare it's values

```
class Kid(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(choices=cities)
```

Then you can filter all kids that comply with your filter and get ids of parents to filter on later

```
filter_ids = Kid.objects.filter(name=X, age__gte=Z, city=Y).values_list('parents_id', flat=True).distinct()
exclude_ids = Kid.objects.filter(name=X, age__lt=Z, city=Y).values_list('parents_id', flat=True).distinct()

parents = Parent.objects.filter(id__in=filter_ids).exclude(id__in=exclude_ids)
```

**Answering comment**
Same logic you firstly fillter all parents with such kids, then you exclude parents that have other kids.

```
filter_ids = Kid.objects.filter(my_pattern).values_list('parents_id', flat=True).distinct()
exclude_ids = Kid.objects.exclude(my_pattern).values_list('parents_id', flat=True).distinct()

parents = Parent.objects.filter(id__in=filter_ids).exclude(id__in=exclude_ids)
```

Comment: what if I have list of objects instead of one? e.g list of parents object that their children include only: 20 name with certain ages and cities for each name?

Comment: My pattern is suppose to be a tuple?

Comment: @DjangoGuy it depends on what you are trying to filter. It can be `name__in=names_list` for example. But this is separate question.

Comment: I want to filter the kid detail as one unit. such as (name=samy, age_lt=20, city=paris) and so on. to find parents objects that includes the allowed filters only. should I start a new question?

Comment: If you have multiple combinations of such pattern as `(name=samy, age_lt=20, city=paris)` use django's Q objects https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects. It will be better if you create a separate question showing us your code. So we can imporve/fix it. Don't forget to accept this answer if solved your problem

Comment: I tried listing names as a tuple under a function view. and didn't work!